# What is the mechanism behind the production of carbon nanotubes via laser ablation?

Tags: material-science, laser, nanoscience

I've been doing some reading on the free-electron laser and its practical applications, one of which seems to be in the (relatively) quick and uniform production of single-wall carbon nanotubes via laser ablation.

I understand that, in what is likely a very hand-wavy sense, laser ablation forms carbon nanotubes by heating small amounts of a carbon-containing target via laser, then letting that cool along the walls of a chamber (typically containing some inert gas) where it somehow forms carbon nanotubes. Somehow the free-electron laser is "better" at this as it causes less heating of/damage to the target (?). Unfortunately, I'm unable to find anything accessible that goes any deeper.

Why is it that these globs of carbon land and cool on the wall precisely such that they form hollow, single-walled tubes? What is the purpose of the inert gas? Need the laser pulses be modulated in some way, or their intensity carefully adjusted such that these tubes form? It's somewhat surprising to me that it seems (relatively) easy to simply shoot a target with a laser and wait for these things to form as the heated carbon cools.

Comment: Well, it forms a bunch of other stuff too… Generally the tubes (used to be?) considered to be formed in the gas phase.